# UV Unwrap doesn't work in render view

Tags: texturing, uv

I've been learning how to use Blender, and I've come across a tutorial which talks about UV Unwrapping, but it isn't the same version of Blender that mine is so I have no idea what to do now. My version is 2.79

The editor looks like this:
[image: The texture is visible]

But when I render it (with F12) it just shows this:
[image: The texture is just grey]

How do I make the render show the texture?

Comment: Could you please provide the .blend file? In the screenshot some of the interesting information is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Blender Internal (as your case), the "Texture" viewport mode shows the texture currently opened during UV Unwrap operations, even with no material assigned to the cube. To show the same texture in rendering you must create a material for the mesh and assign the texture to it, as shown in picture.

[image]